# Pattern matching on string

Tags: ocaml

say i have the following type definition:

```
type e = AES | DES | SALSA20
```

Then, i have a function which has an argument of **type string**, this argument could be "AES", "DES", "SALSA20", or something else. How could I first turn this string into a type and then match this type with possible types? Or, is it necessary because one may argue you can just match a string directly as the following?

```
match str with
| "AES" -> do something...
| "DES" -> do something else...
```

If possible, can I also get a basic intro to how pattern-matching works on string? I feel direct string matching will be much slower...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a function like this:

```
let e_of_string = function
| "AES" -> AES
| "DES" -> DES
| "SALSA20" -> SALSA20
| _ -> raise (Invalid_argument "e_of_string")
```

I examined the native code generated by OCaml 4.01.0; it compares the supplied string against each of the given strings in order. If there are a lot of strings to check, this is, as you say, pretty slow.

To get more powerful string matching, you could use regular expressions from the `Str` module, or you could use ocamllex.

Comment: Since OCaml 4.02 pattern matching on strings is _much_ faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it either way. If you are going to perform multiple matches then mapping the string to a data type first makes a lot of sense. For just a single match, I would pick whichever leads to the most straightforward code (or the most consistent, if this is something that is done elsewhere in your code base).

Mapping to a type might look something like:

```
type thing = AES | DES | SALSA20

let thing_of_string = function
  | "AES" -> AES
  | "DES" -> DES
  | "SALSA20" -> SALSA20
  | _ -> failwith "not a thing"
```

String matching was improved recently and should be acceptably efficient for what it is. I would still avoid performing the same string match many times.